# Javascript Chrome Extension fetch request in loop with delays

Tags: javascript, html, loops, google-chrome-extension, fetch

I am working on a chrome extension to do fetch requests on a website. So there are two buttons, one of them is a "On" "Off" button.

`<button id="add_loop" class="btn button" style="margin-top: 10px;">START</button>`

```
var start= false;
fetch_start.addEventListener("click", async () => { //eventlistener for the on off button

  start = !start;

  chrome.storage.sync.set({'start_fetch': start});
  
  if(start){
    bot_start.innerHTML = "ON";
  }
  else{
    bot_start.innerHTML = "OFF";
  }
  
})
```

Then when i click on the other button, it checks if its On or Off. If it's off, it will do only one fetch request. This works. If It's On, it should do fetch requests in a loop with a delay inbetween.

```
function doRequest(){ 
   
      chrome.storage.sync.get("start_fetch", ({start_fetch}) => {
      
      
      if(!start_fetch){
        console.log("ONE FETCH");
        //fetch request
      }

}
```

Can someone help please? Thank you!

Comment: Use `setInterval` and `clearInterval`

Comment: gonna take a look on it, thank you!